# What can I to improve my grades in MS in computer science and engineering, when they are poor because of inadequate background in math?

Tags: masters, coursework

I am studying Graduate MSc in CSE. Due to inadequate knowledge in Statistics/Calculus, my grades are getting bad.

What would be the best way to save my grades?

I am considering, skipping this program, getting a diploma in Math and then coming back again.

Can you suggest any better option?

Comment: Buy a used copy of *Thomas's Calculus* from someplace like eBay.  Start at chapter one.

Comment: Tutoring might also come in handy.

Comment: Perhaps you need to make a more careful selection of computer science classes to take, that will fit your talents and disposition better.  Many computer scientists never use any knowledge of calculus.